# How should I bridge TCP traffic using C#? Need to copy traffic on one port and send it to another

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcpclient

I need to bridge traffic from one port (say port 3000) and send it to a new port (say port 4000) and have full bidirectional TCP support.

How should I go about solving this?  Should I use the socket class or the TCPClient class?

Would this be as simple as sending the stream of data from one TCPClient to another?

Is there anything else I should be considering?

Comment: I'm not sure this is something that should be done with a program. Are you sure you can't use iptables/routes for this (i.e. let the routers take care of it)?

Comment: @LueTM I'm a windows person but am open to a iptables solution.  It's taking me too long to figure out the iptables, but I'm open to whatever you know...

Answer (score 2):

You program needs to act as both a server *and* a client:

It should act at a server regarding port 3000, where your program receives connections. Each time you receive a new connection you yourself create a new connection to the actual server on port 4000. Keep these two connections (the one initiated on port 3000 and the one you created to port 4000) together, so you know they are a pair. When you receive data on any of these connection, just send it on the the other connection in the pair.

Answer (score 0):

Found an solution for myself for a similar task.

1. The app should work as TCP listener (server) on local port, say, 3000.
2. The app should work as TCP client, connected to some other port, say, 4000. Not matter is it a local open for incoming connections or a some remote.
3. Get `NetworkStream` instance for each TCP object. The example below is for remote part:

```
TcpClient TunnelToRemote = new();
TunnelToRemote.Connect("192.168.123.123", 4000);
RemoteStream = TunnelToRemote.GetStream();
//also we have ClientStream, which made in same manner
```

4. Bridge the streams:

```
bool TunnelAlive = true;
try
{
    BinaryReader BRclient = new(ClientStream);
    BinaryWriter BWclient = new(ClientStream);
    BinaryReader BRremote = new(RemoteStream);
    BinaryWriter BWremote = new(RemoteStream);

    new Task(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                BWremote.Write(BRclient.ReadByte());
            }
        }
        catch { TunnelAlive = false; }
    }).Start();

    new Task(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                BWclient.Write(BRremote.ReadByte());
            }
        }
        catch { TunnelAlive = false; }
    }).Start();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.WriteLine(" Tunnel error: {0}. Closing.", ex.ToString());
    TunnelAlive = false;
};

// Wait while connecion is alive
while (TunnelAlive)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    TunnelAlive = (ClientStream as NetworkStream).Socket.Connected;
};
```

5. Profit. Not perfect, but working.